# Firestore - get documents by item in array of object in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

If we have a collection like:

```
Courses:
 Math:
    id: 1001
    students: [
        {id: 100, name: "Alex"},
        {id: 101, name: "mark"}
    ]
 Physics:
    id: 1002
    students: [
        {id: 100, name: "Alex"},
        {id: 103, name: "arnold"}
    ]
```

how we can get all courses for a specific student?
e.g. getting all courses assigned to Alex.

Comment: I think this article, [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073), can add more info, regarding search and update, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

we can get it in 2 ways:

1. by an **object** of Student class:

```
val alex = Student(100, "Alex")

firestore.collection("Courses")
            .whereArrayContains("students", alex))
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener{}
```

2. using a **Map** of Student data:

```
firestore.collection("Courses")
            .whereArrayContains("students", mapOf("id" to 100, "name" to "Alex")))
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener{}
```

this will return the following docs:
**[Math, Physics]**